# How to create .world from .yaml

Tags: simulation, yaml, ros-hydro, stage, world

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a map (the .png file and the .yaml file) and I want to create a .world file, how to do this?
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188933/how-to-create-.world-from-.yaml/) by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-08-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I see that the question is old, but if it helps, I recently ran into similar problem and summarized the solution in this [blog post](https://medium.com/@ivangavran/ros-creating-world-file-from-existing-yaml-5b553d31cc53#.88e8vmwuh)

There are two key points:

1. align coordinate systems of .world and .yaml files
2. add a black border around the map image because otherwise Stage would shrink the map.

---

Originally posted by [gavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/26097/gavran/) with karma: 526 on 2016-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2